# User's latitude and longitude isn't passed to new view controller

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager, uistoryboardsegue

I have a button that gets the user's current latitude / longitude using CLLocationManager, and I am trying to pass both the latitude / longitude into a new view controller. Getting the latitude / longitude works, but when I try to pass the the data into my new view controller, it's not getting passed.

```
func getCurrentLocation() {
      locationManager.delegate = self
      locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
      locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
      locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let currentLocation: CLLocation = locations[0]
    self.userLongtitude = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude
    self.userLatitude = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ListOfEventsTableViewController
    if segue.identifier == "useCurrentLocation" {
        getCurrentLocation()

        destinationVC.userCurrentLat = self.userLatitude
        destinationVC.userCurrentLong = self.userLongtitude
    }
}
```

Any help?

---

Edit:

```
func getCurrentLocation() {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestLocation()
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    if let location = locations.first {
        self.userLongtitude = location.coordinate.longitude
        self.userLatitude = location.coordinate.latitude

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("useCurrentLocation", sender: nil)
    }
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ListOfEventsTableViewController
    if segue.identifier == "useCurrentLocation" {            
        destinationVC.userCurrentLat = self.userLatitude
        destinationVC.userCurrentLong = self.userLongtitude
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that getting the users location is asynchronous. This means you need to push the new view controller when the location is available (for example in `didUpdateLocations`). Or try to get the users location earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` in the `CLLocationManager` class isn't instant, I believe. So the way you have it set up, you are expecting it to save a value for latitude and longitude immediately when you call `getCurrentLocation()`

This is taken from Apple's documentation on `CLLocationManager`

> Calling it causes the location manager to obtain a location fix (which may take several seconds) and call the delegate’s locationManager:didUpdateLocations: method with the result.

I would recommend placing a `performSegueWithIdentifier` inside the `didUpdateLocations` method so we know that latitude and longitude are set then. Also, if you only need the latitude and longitude at certain points in the app then I would recommend using `CLLocationManager` `requestLocation` method where it updates the location once rather than constantly fetching the location which is needed for something like a map app.